# How to get merged cell row/column span in OpenOffice Calc Macro

Tags: openoffice-calc

I can detect if a given cell in a sheet is merged with `sheet.getCellByPosition(0,0).IsMerged`

Is there any way to discover the width/height of the merged cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First figure out which rows or columns the cell spans.  For example, say we want to figure out how wide a cell is that spans two columns.

Then for each column involved, find out how wide it is, and add up the widths.  This code, adapted from https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=19790, determines the width of a column:

```vb
Sub GetColumnWidth
    dim oSheet as object, oDoc As Object
    dim w as single
    dim col as integer
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oSheet = ThisComponent.getCurrentController.getActiveSheet
    col = 1  'column B
    oColumn = oSheet.getColumns.getByIndex( col )
    'column width (in 100ths of mm)
    w = oColumn.Width / 2540
    MsgBox w
End Sub
```

One more thing, it looks like there is a [ShrinkToFit](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/table/CellProperties.html#ShrinkToFit) property.  I did not test whether that gets reflected in the `Width` property.